# How can I search for slash (\) in MySQL? And why is escaping (\) not required for where (=), but for Like it is required?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping

Consider this QUERY ([DEMO IS HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7284/1))

```
(SELECT * FROM `titles` where title = 'test\\')
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `titles` where title LIKE 'test\\\\')
```

Output:

```
| ID | TITLE |
--------------
|  1 | test\ |
|  1 | test\ |
```

### QUESTION:

Why no extra **(\)** required for **(=)** but for (like) additional **\\** is required?
Its clear that MySQL escaped the **(test\)** with **(test\\)** then using **(test\\\\)** is logical for LIKE.

Table information:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `titles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `titles`
--

INSERT INTO `titles` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'test\\');
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html Test it in `BINARY` comparison mode and you won't need the extra \\.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7284/8 (whoops link updated)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`\` functions as an escape character in `LIKE` by default.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for `LIKE`:

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\\n”. To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped **once by the parser** and **again when the pattern match is made**, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

You can change this by specifying another escape character, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM `titles` WHERE title LIKE 'test\\' ESCAPE '|'
```

Comment: Thanks, satisfying answer :) (+1 for ESCAPE also)

Comment: For added clarity, here is an example of what the query should look like if you're trying to escape the backslash and have changed the ESCAPE character to pipe: SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%|\%' ESCAPE '|'

Answer (score 73):

Actually, all previous answers have been mangled somewhere. As you can see in the link provided by Karoly Horvath, whose significant bit is reproduced by Explosion Pills, **the correct way of searching for 1 backslash (\) is to use 4 backslashes at once (\\\\)**.

By the way, to show above that single backslash I had to use two at once and to show those four I had to use eight.

Comment: This is right. As per mysql documentation : **Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. [...] To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”**

Comment: I have corrected the answer by Karoly Horvath to show the correct number of backslashes.

Comment: If your query is embedded in Java code, you'll need 8 backslashes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For me it works with 3 backslashes: \\\

Comment: To add to the party, if you're coding the escaped sequence into string that needs escaped slashes, you'll potentially be typing up to 8 of them!  Enjoy!

Comment: Nice point! tnx

Comment: this seems to work when your collation is latin1_swedish_ci, but not when the collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci (it seems you need 5 backslashes in that case, no idea why...)

Answer (score 9):

For finding a `\` within a text field I had to escape the `\` twice, else the `%` at the end was found:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where `field` LIKE '%\\\%';
```

Comment: According to the manual, the question itself, and two other answers here, **4** backslashes are required. Are you sure this works correctly with **3** backslashes? If so, that is intriguing.

Comment: I can confirm that (at least on MariaDB v10.0.33) 3 backslashes works the exact same way as 4 backslashes.

Answer (score 8):

`LIKE` accepts two wildchar characters, `%` and `_`.

To be able to match these characters, escaping can be used: `\%`, `\_`. This also means that if you want to match `\`, it has to be escaped as well.

All this is documented in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks for additional Info.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanted to remove the (') from the database column (Test's) and replace it with apostrophe (Test's) then you can use the following query.

```
SELECT replace(column_name, "\\'", "'") FROM table where column_name  LIKE "%\\\%";
```