# How to search for the backslash (\) mark and the zero (0) in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

## **Summary/Background**

I have tried to make a search engine that can search for any characters in MySQL. But I encounter some question below:

1. When I try to search for the backslash (\) mark, the result is unwanted. (The result shows many data that don't contain the backslash)
2. When I try to search for the number zero (0), the result is NONE no matter what the content is.

## **My Try**

I have tried to describe the problem. And below is the code.

```
<?
$search="\\";        //The searching word. (Here I wanna search for the word backslash (\).)
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","ooo");
mysql_select_db("xxx",$link);

if($search){
    $str="select xxx from Sheet where xxx like '%$search%'";
    $list=mysql_query($str,$link);
    while(list($xxx)=mysql_fetch_row($list)){
            echo $xxx."<br>";
    }
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

## **The data in my database**

Below is the data in my database: (xxx is the field in the datasheet `Sheet`)

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| xxx                                       |
+===========================================+
| Happy % ^_^                               |
| Hello! \Hello\                            |
| /\?"'                                     |
| ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><`1234567890-=\][';/.,|
| Oh! My God!!!                             |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Logically speaking, the PHP page should print out the result of:

```
Hello! \Hello\
/\?"'
~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><`1234567890-=\][';/.,
```

But actually the result is:

```
Happy % ^_^ 
~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><`1234567890-=\][';/.,
```

Why it happens like that?

## **The similar question**

> [How to search for slash (\) in MySQL? and why escaping (\) not required for where (=) but for Like is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926386/how-to-search-for-slash-in-mysql-and-why-escaping-not-required-for-wher)
>
> You can change this by specifying another escape character, as in:
>
> `SELECT * FROM titles where title LIKE 'test\\' ESCAPE '|'`

In which an answerer proposed adding “ESCAPE '|'” in the end of the SQL statement, but the whole problem doesn't be solved. It's just transferring the same problem to the other character (|). So is there any better way to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have figured from other Q&As backlash is an escape keyword for LIKE expression. However you can use three (some suggested four) backslashes to escape them.

I've tested the expression `LIKE '%\\\%'` will match input `'mom\dad'`

Comment: If you use three backslashes to escape them, you might get the error like that: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'localhost' (T_STRING) in /public_html/test.php on line 3`

Comment: Then you have to account the backslash eaten by PHP parser

Comment: But the result is same as above.
It still show those two results:`Happy % ^_^ ` and
`~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><1234567890-=\][';/.,`

Comment: In spite of using either three or four backslashes, it still show the same result.