# How to use mySQL to search an escaped string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having the strangest issue:

I'm trying to get a count of a column with this as the data format:

```
"{\"errors\":0,\"results\":{\"isError\":true,\"errorCode\":305,\"errorString\":\"Contact already exists: test@gmail.com\"}}"
```

It's a string with escape characters in it.

I'm trying to search on `isError:true`, and nothing I'm doing is working.

I've tried

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE "%isError\":true%"`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE '%isError\":true%'`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE '%isError":true%'`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE '%isError\\":true%'`

all with zero results.

How can I search on this escaped string?

Here's the full data.  Keep in mind it's stored as a string.

`"{\"errors\":0,\"results\":{\"isError\":true,\"errorCode\":305,\"errorString\":\"Contact already exists: test@gmail.com\"}}"`

It's store exactly like in a TEXT type column that outer quotes and everything.

(This is a legacy system I'm working on.)

Comment: Tried `'%isError\\":true%'`?

Comment: Also worth a peek: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63829

Comment: Yep '%isError\\":true%' . no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

To search for an escape backslash in a string, with LIKE, you have to use FOUR backslashes.  Not intutive but there it is.

[How to search for slash (\) in MySQL? and why escaping (\) not required for where (=) but for Like is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926386/how-to-search-for-slash-in-mysql-and-why-escaping-not-required-for-wher)

Thank you for the help. Hope this help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The data sample you show looks like JSON. There are functions in MySQL 5.7 to search JSON structures: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

There's no reason to store backslashes in the database. Did you accidentally double-escape when you inserted this data?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the backslash in MySQL is also an escape symbol, and that's the only thing that needs to be escaped in your query (if you use single quotes, which you should anyway). To escape the backslash, simply repeat it:

```
select * from mytable where col like '%isError\\":true%'
```

Bill makes a good point though--you're better off in the long run storing the JSON differently.

Comment: Yeah I know! I wouldnt' have done this way at all.  This is legacy code. And I've tried that way and doesn't work.

Comment: @NickKiermaier Hmm, it works here. If it doesn’t work for you, the data may not be stored exactly as you think. Can you show exactly the output of a `select` statement?