# Can't replace a specific string that contains \/ in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

In my database table there is a column that contains a value like this:

```
{"type":"XXX\\ZZZ\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"XXX\\ZZZ\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"category_ids","operator":"{}","value":"7","is_value_processed":false},{"type":"XXX\\ZZZ\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"category_ids","operator":"!()","value":"73, 223, 1078, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1080, 1081, 1082, 1093, 1059, 1060, 1057, 1085, 1106, 1105, 1107, 1103","is_value_processed":false},{"type":"vendor_module\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales","attribute":false,"operator":"is_not_on_sales","value":false,"is_value_processed":false}]}
```

I want to replace the specific string which is `vendor_module\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales` into `Vendor\\Module\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Onsales\\Onsales` by doing it like this:

```
UPDATE table
          SET column = REPLACE(column, 'vendor_module\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales', 'Vendor\\Module\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Onsales\\Onsales')
          WHERE column LIKE '%vendor_module\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales%';
```

but i always get a response `0 row updated`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search for slash (\‌) in MySQL? and why escaping (\‌) not required for where (=) but for Like is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926386/how-to-search-for-slash-in-mysql-and-why-escaping-not-required-for-wher)

Comment: and you can view this example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/thbW5znCqBeQdQ7Qp1UpzF/1

Comment: @tcadidot0 thanks it works for finding the value and replacing it by using the `escape '|'` and add extra slash in `REPLACE` and `LIKE` function `vendor_module\\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales`, but the value replaced by `Vendor\Module\Rule\Condition\Product\\Onsales\Onsales` instead of `Vendor\\Module\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Onsales\\Onsales`

Comment: the string that you want to replace also need to be escaped the same way

Comment: see this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/thbW5znCqBeQdQ7Qp1UpzF/3

Answer (score 0):

The string `'%vendor_module\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales%'` in LIKE clause contains backslash `"\"`. You have to change the `\` in LIKE to `\\\\`. For example `%vendor_module\\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales%'`