# MySQL LIKE Operator with Special Characters Confusion

Tags: mysql

First let me apologize I have not been successful in finding anything online with this specific scenario.
I have been using MySQL for quite some time, but I am hoping to get some clarification on a certain situation I have come across, which honestly bothers me quite a bit.

I'm trying to match a string in a MySQL column that contains both `\` and `%` literal characters using the LIKE operator.

Inside the table I have two records:

```
id          value
-----------------------
1           100\\%A
2           100\%A
```

They both contain literal special characters.

### If I do a SELECT, in an attempt to only match the first record (id=1), I would expect to write the query as such:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value LIKE '%0\\\\\%A'`
(`\\\\` to match two literal backslashes, plus a backslash before `%` to match a literal `%`)

However, It only matches the row (id=2), which makes no sense to me.

### If I change the query a little to be:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value LIKE '%0\\\\%A'`
I would expect to match the id=1 row only, (`\\\\` to match 2 literal backslashes, and the `%` *is not* literal and should represent a wildcard). But instead, it matches both rows?

row (id=2) only has a single backslash but still matches.

Is row id=2 matching because the first 2 backslashes are matching the `\`, the 3rd backslash is ignored for some reason, and the 4th backslash is allowing a literal match on the `%`?

### If I do a:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value LIKE '%0\\\\\\\%A'`

I for some reason get row (id=1), when I would expect to get no matches whatsoever.

I'm trying to find a solution in which I can do partial matches on any series of characters accurately, including those with consecutive special characters such as the scenario above. However, I'm having an impossible time trying to plan for situations such as these.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MySQL and what is your client?  (There are cases where 2 backslashes are needed and cases where 4 are needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this help you understand the usage of escape chars in mySQL

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27061961/634698